# Delete old Applications Physical folders from Service Fabric on-Premise

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to delete old packages from Service Fabric On premise Via Powershell. I tried to un-register but it doesn't delete the folders from nodes and I am unable to find the ImageStore Package Path (if exist) to run Remove-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [imagestore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-image-store-connection-string) service holds the packages as its State.

[Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications) applications by using

```
Remove-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore MyApplicationV1 -ImageStoreConnectionString (Get-ImageStoreConnectionStringFromClusterManifest (Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest))
```

Comment: Tried that already, it said "Remove application package succeeded"  and did nothing. I tried it with applicationTypeName "Pacaya.ServiceFabricApplicationType" and i also tried with "Pacaya.ServiceFabricApplicationType@1.0.0.139519" is that the right format? also it doesn't metter what i put instead of "MyApplicationV1" it said the same thing "Remove application package succeeded" . any idea what am i missing?

Comment: Hello Again, so i saw that this actually does work if i wait after i run the command for about 30 minutes... thank you very much for your help. i still think the command has a bug as it return "Remove application package succeeded" on everything